# which is the best template for news site in share point 2010?

Tags: site-template

I need to create site for organization news.which is the best template for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For internal organization news site I personally prefer blog site template as it allows editors to post/edit news from Word along with images and everything. Very user friendly.